# Importing modules at runtime, python

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a module, modify the module's code and reimport (hot reload) this same module with the new updates without actually stopping and restarting the script using the module.

I know of `reload` method from `importlib` library but it does not seem to do what I want.

So my current plan is to programmatically reimport this module after making the changes. Something like this:

```
importlib.import_module('my_module')
```

but what I'm not sure of is if importing it this way will actually reread the content the module so as to get the updates. If not could you please provide a way of achieving this?

Comment: `importlib.import_module('my_module')` will not `reload` the module. This is same as `__import__`, but the `importlib` is recommended. And you certainly shouldn't `reload` modules at runtime

Comment: Thanks @han solo, but any reason why I shouldn't `reload` modules at runtime?

Comment: Say, you have a class `Foo` from a module `foo` loaded somewhere, and this `Foo` is referenced by other code. Now you reload `foo`, but the previous reference is not `reloaded`, and is used by some code. Thus you get `zombies`. I am not sure, if i explained myself clearly, let me see if i can find some links